# MySQL/PHP: Adding, updating and retrieving data using Ajax but all 3 share the same php file? Is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, file

So in a file I have a form of which **you add in a database**, another form of which you **retrieve** and another of which you **update**. All forms are sending information using javascript (ajax) to some php files.

For example:

**// Add data**

```
function get(str) {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtuser").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxget.php?q=" + str, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**// Update data**

```
function update() {
    var ud_id = $('.ud_id').attr('value');
    var ud_first = $('.ud_first').attr('value');
    var ud_last = $('.ud_last').attr('value');

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtuser").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxupdate.php?ud_id=" + ud_id + "&ud_first=" + ud_first + "&ud_last=" + ud_last , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
```

**// Add new data**

```
function add() {
    var add_ud_first = $('.add_ud_first').attr('value');
    var add_ud_last = $('.add_ud_last').attr('value');

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtuser").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxadd.php?add_ud_first=" + add_ud_first + "&add_ud_last=" + add_ud_last , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
```

As you can see all snippets send to `ajaxget.php`, `ajaxupdate.php` and `ajaxadd.php` accordingly. **Can I combine those files so I have 1 php of which called by all snippets?**

So for example, all snippets will call the ajax.php file and within that file, if the get() calls it, then do accordingly.

Does that make sense?

Here is one ajaxget.php file:

```
<?php   include("connection.php");

$q=$_GET["q"];


$query="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "Name: " . $row['first'] . " <br />";
  echo "Surname: " . $row['last'] . " <br />";
  }

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You need something akin to a controller: ajaxaction.php?action=add&q=....

Comment: @MyStream something like that I had in mind. I am a very beginner. Where do I start reading?

Comment: Consider using jQuery for your AJAX stuff on the client side. Right now your code will break in old browsers that do not have the `XMLHttpRequest` object. And you already use jQuery anyway.. so use it for AJAX, too. Oh, and the proper way to get the value of an element is `.val()` and **never** `.attr('value')`!

Comment: Would an object oriented way of breaking down the functions suit your needs better - see my comment below for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a parameter to your request (either POST or GET) to determine the type of request it is.

For example if you send a GET parameter (`?operation=insert`) then in the PHP code you should use a switch/if-else to execute the correct code.

```
$allowed_operations = array('insert', 'update', 'delete');
if(    isset($_GET['operation']) 
    && in_array(isset($_GET['operation']), $allowed_operations)){
    switch($_GET['operation']){
        case 'insert':
            // do insert operation here
            break;
        case 'update':
            // do update operation here
            break;
        case 'delete':
            //do delete operation here
            break;
    }
}
```

#### Edit 1

1. put all the code of `ajaxget.php`, `ajaxupdate.php` and `ajaxadd.php` in `ajaxop.php` or anything else.
2. Keep the `ajaxget.php` contents in a function `ajax_get()` and same for others.
3. Change the `xmlhttp.open` so that it calls only `ajaxop.php` and in the URI add `operation=get`, `operation=update` etc according to you need.
4. Map those parameters in the switch statement.

Comment: This is all my php files comined: http://pastebin.com/DJibLnt6 . So each section I add underneath the case section?

Comment: line 5 will break if no GET is supplied, consider a LIMIT clause on line 8, consider stripslashes() on 14 and 15, 24-26 will break if no GET is supplied,

Comment: yes, you would add each of your different operations between the case and break statements.  Of course if your logic for these operations gets more complicated, you might want to look at encapsulating the actions into objects that you simply call with the parameters you're getting from the AJAX request.  Based on your pastebin example though, you don't need to get that complicated yet.

Comment: @JohnyBryne put each of your sections in a function and call those functions from the switch case body.

Comment: My personal preference is to use an include by name or dispatch using $method = 'do_'.$methodName, so you don't have to keep writing switch statements.  This way's fine, but more work to extend because you have to write a new switch as well as a new $allowed_operation entry, but same logic - all good.

Comment: Can you please check this bin: http://pastebin.com/n38U3Kae I think the xmlhttp is wrong

Answer (score 2):

A *very* simple approach:

```
<?php

$action = 'list';

$arrActions = array ('list', 'add', 'update', 'delete');

if(isset($_GET['action']) && in_array($_GET['action'],$arrActions)) {
 include('ajax_action_'.$_GET['action'].'.php');
} else {
 include('ajax_action_list.php');
}

?>
```

With a simple file iike this you can 'route' your requests to other files ahd have those deal with them internally.  There is a lot more to consider, but if you're starting out, keep it simple like this and then you'll be able to pick up elements you need specifically for your application in due time.

**UPDATE**

An issue was raised about number of files:

This might help:

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

class controller {
  private $arrMethods = array('get','list','add','update','delete');

  public function __construct() {
   if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $method = 'do'.ucwords($_GET['action']); // list=>List, add=>Add, etc
    if(method_exists($method,$this)) {
      $this->$method();
    }
  }

  public function doGet () {

     $q=(int)(isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET["q"] : 0);

     if(0 < (int)$q) {

        $query="SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `id` = '$q'"; // limit to 1?
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result && mysql_error()=='' && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo "Name: " . stripslashes($row['first']) . " <br />";
              echo "Surname: " . stripslashes($row['last']) . " <br />";
          }
        }

        mysql_close();
     }
  }

  public function doList () {

  } 

  public function doAdd () {

  }

  public function doEdit () {

  }

  public function doDelete () {

  }
}

$objController = new controller();

?>
```

This now becomes your gateway script with each function separated out.

Does this give you a better starting point?

Comment: Thank you. I would like to have as less files as possible. Your way seems that I have to still have the same amount of files.

Answer (score 1):

add an argument `?action=add`, or whatever. Your php script can check it and call an appropriate function with the `q` argument. But before you do anything else, google "SQL injection attack"

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action']
if $action == 'add' {
  // add code
}
elseif $action == 'update' {
  // update code
}
elseif $action == 'delete' {
  // delete code
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that. What do I have to have in my php file though? How will it know which ones I'm calling? Also about the SQL injection, a fellow mentioned it before. I am beginner, slowly I will get there.

Comment: This are all the php files combined. How does it know which I am calling? http://pastebin.com/DJibLnt6

Comment: Have a single php file, and use it for all ajax calls. When the file runs, the first thing it does is check the action argument `$_GET['action']`. Depending on its value, you run the right part of the code (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

It kinda looks like you are trying to build something like a REST api. I suggest you check this one: http://www.slimframework.com, and other sources for information about RESTful interfaces. Modifying the data between browser and server use REST api will also have the added benefit when front-end JavaScript frameworks like Backbone will semi-automatically understand it with minimal hassle.

Just sayin'.